# SPSS - DO IF ELSE IF Loop not closing

Tags: spss

I'm trying to write a Syntax in SPSS to look at a listed variable (FYCount) and code a new variable (FYStart) with a date that corresponds to the FYCount. Because there are 13 different FYCount variables, I've tried to do it efficiently with a DO IF ELSE IF loop, but it tells me that I haven't closed the loop. I've toggled with it for a while now and don't see why it isn't closing and executing the command. Any help for this beginner-level question would be much-appreciated!

Here's the code I have:

```
do if FYCount = 1.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2003).
else if FYCount = 2.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2004).
else if FYCount = 3.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2005).
else if FYCount = 4.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2006).
else if FYCount = 5.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2007).
else if FYCount = 6.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2008).
else if FYCount = 7.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2009).
else if FYCount = 8.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2010).
else if FYCount = 9.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2011).
else if FYCount = 10.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2012).
else if FYCount = 11.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2013).
else if FYCount = 12.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2014).
else if FYCount = 13.
compute FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2015).
end if.
```

When I run it, I get this message:
Warning # 142.  Command name: EXECUTE 
LOOP has no effect on this command.

Error # 4095.  Command name: EXECUTE 
The transformations program contains an unclosed LOOP, DO IF, or complex file 
structure.  Use the level-of-control shown to the left of the SPSS Statistics 
commands to determine the range of LOOPs and DO IFs. 
Execution of this command stops

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks good, no obvious errors.

The error message suggest you may have an `EXECUTE` and a `DO IF` or `LOOP` in the syntax before or after this series of `DO IF` statements.

Try executing all commands before this syntax to ensure the error isn't relating to something before or after. Then run this syntax alone. Close the session down and restart if necessary.

Also make sure you don't have any other nested `DO IF` activated. It's likely you are missing a terminating full stop somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is actually your code, try this:

```
COMPUTE FYStart = date.dmy(1,7,2002 + FYCount).
```